# Can I upload files to one Windows share and expose them on another?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, symbolic-link

So I've got a Windows server with a couple of fileshares, call them `ShareA` and `ShareB`. `ShareA` is read/write accessible to only a couple of admins, and `ShareB` is read-only for all. The files on the server live side by side at `D:\ShareA` and `D:\ShareB`.

There's a folder on `ShareA` that I would like to expose to `ShareB`, so that the admins can change the contents of that folder from wherever they have `ShareA` mounted, and those contents will be automatically made accessible to the users of `ShareB`.

Is this possible? I've tried symlinks so far without success -- they don't appear to be abstracted by the file server as would be needed.

---

I am specifically trying to avoid altering share permissions here, like giving the admins write access to `ShareB`, or (vice-versa) everyone else read-only for the directory in `ShareA`. This question is specifically about how to avoid doing that in the most elegant way possible.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking but I'll take a shot at it: Create a shortcut for the ShareA folder in question. Put said shortcut into ShareB.

Comment: @joeqwerty Shortcuts behave much the same way as symlinks here -- the windows share presents the shortcut, which is linking to `D:\ShareA\SomeFolder`, which the client system knows nothing about.

Comment: Well, _almost_ nothing. There appears to be some magic going on whereby if you have `ShareA` mounted, Windows knows where it's supposed to be going even though the shortcut itself is talking about D: which doesn't exist, but the non-admin clients won't have that share mounted.

Comment: Distributed Link Tracking takes care of that, but as you stated, will probably only work for clients that have ShareA mounted. I don't have a way to test this out but it should be relatively easy for you to test this and either prove or disprove it. OK, I was able to test it and it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think know what you are trying to do. I do this and don't have any problems.

Windows supports two types of 'symlinks' - known as junctions.

One is a local link where you have `d:\shareA\myDirlink`  - shared as `\\srv\sharea`
the other is`d:\shareB\Mydir` - shared as `\\srv\shareb`

you can create mydirlink as a junction (like a unix hardlink) to `d:\shareb\mydir`
Or you can create it as a link to `\\shareb\mydir`

you will want the former. The junction.exe from sysinternals.com (i.e MS) or the mklink.exe programs will both serve well.

All you do is create a junction in d:\sharea pointing at `d:\shareb\mydir`. You will need to set read access (NTFS permissions) to the directory and its subcontents for your `\\srv\sharea` users, but once set theres no more to it.

Another alternative is to simply share `d:\shareb\mydir` as `\\srv\mydir-rw`

and grant access to it to the admin group you mentioned.

Comment: OH SWEET! I didn't know how junctions worked -- looks like they behave a little bit like hard links for directories. Works great!